# how to get column from listview in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, datagrid

If we are using the DataGrid to get the value from the column I can use

```
var a = datagrid1.Columns[1].GetCellContent(item)
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I get the same value when using ListView instead of DataGrid. This ListView contains a GridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> xaml

```
 <ListView Margin="10" Name="UsersList" SelectionChanged="UsersList_SelectionChanged_1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid x:Name="colGrid">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" x:Name="txtBlock"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid x:Name="colGrid">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" x:Name="txtBlock"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid x:Name="colGrid">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mail}" x:Name="txtBlock"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

> SelectionChanged Event Handler of List View

```
        private void UsersList_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var gridView = UsersList.View as GridView;
        ListBoxItem myListBoxItem =UsersList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(UsersList.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;

        //ContentControl does not directly host the elements provided by the expanded DataTemplate.  
        //It uses a ContentPresenter to do the  work. 
        //If we want to use the FindName method we will have to pass that ContentPresenter as the second argument, instead of the ContentControl. 
        ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = myListBoxItem.GetVisualChild<ContentPresenter>();

        foreach (var column in gridView.Columns)
        {
            //Here using FindName we can get the controls of cell template
            var grid = column.CellTemplate.FindName("colGrid", myContentPresenter);
        }
    }
```

> Visual Helper

```
    public static class VisualHelper
{
    public static T GetVisualChild<T>(this Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);

        for (int index = 0; index < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); index++)
        {
            Visual visualChild = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, index);
            child = visualChild as T;

            if (child == null)
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(visualChild);//Find Recursively

            else
                return child;
        }
        return child;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help.